# Swift: Does using Swift in An iOS project have to pack libswiftCore.dylib in the ipa file?

Tags: ios, swift

I only add one Swift class in my iOS project, and after archive the ipa file, I see a 6MB file named `libswiftCore.dylib` under a folder named `Frameworks`, this will make my ipa file larger, is there any way to exclude this `libswiftCore.dylib` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, at the moment there's no way to ship application that uses swift without that extra dylib.

The reason is that the internals of swift runtime/std library are not finalized yet and so to avoid backward compatibility problems between different versions the specific dynamic library version has to be shipped with every app that uses swift. That should be fixed some time in future.